# SQL getting counts for several rows grouped by a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I am trying to count multiple individual rows for each column. Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
select (select top 1 name
          from chap
         where chap.chp_id = CHS.chp_id) as Chap,
       (select count(*)
          from CHS,
               chap 
         where O_TYPE = 'PRESIDENT'
           and chs.chp_id = chap.chp_id) as Presidents,
       (select count(*)
          from CHS 
         where O_TYPE = 'VICEPRESIDENT') as VicePresidents,
       (select count(*)
          from CHS 
         where OFFICER_TYPE = 'CORRSECRETARY') as CorrespondinSecretaries,
       (select count(*)
          from CHS 
         where O_TYPE = 'RECORDINGSECRETARY') as RecordingSecretaries,
       (select count(*)
          from CHS 
         where O_TYPE = 'TREASURER') as Treasurers,
       (select count(*)
          from CHS 
         where O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR'
           and ADV_CODE = 'B') as ChiefAdvisors,
       (select count(*)
          from CHS 
         where O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR'
           and ADV_CODE <> 'B') as ChiefAdvisors
from CHS
where O_TYPE in ('PRESIDENT', 'VICEPRESIDENT', 'CORRSECRETARY', 'RECORDINGSECRETARY', 'TREASURER', 'ADVISOR')
  and Term_expire >= DateAdd(Day,DateDiff(Day,0,GetDate()),0)
  and Term_Begin <= DateAdd(Day,DateDiff(Day,0,GetDate()),0)
  and CHS.CHP_ID in (Select chp_id 
                            from chrs
                           where active = 'Y') 
Group by chs.CHP_ID
```

when I run this it totals each row with all of the records not just the records for that chapter. Any suggestions?

Output Example

```
AL A    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
AL B    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
AL G    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
AL D    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
AK A    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
AZ A    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
AZ B    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
AZ G    247 264 247 250 246 235 739
```

What I really want is

```
AL A 1 1 1 4 8 9 16
AL B 1 1 5 7 8 9 21
```

Comment: You need ***conditional aggregation*** where `COUNT` is emulated by `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0)`

Comment: "count multiple individual rows for each column" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing all subqueries as calculated columns with first *name* simply being a `JOIN` to main table. For counts use conditional aggregation by summing the conditions. Additionally, adjust the `GROUP BY` to include *name* and not unique id which may be reason for repetitious data. Also, check term date ranges in `WHERE` as they appear to be redundant.

```
SELECT chap.name AS Chap,
       SUM(O_TYPE = 'PRESIDENT') AS Presidents,
       SUM(O_TYPE = 'VICEPRESIDENT') AS VicePresidents,
       SUM(OFFICER_TYPE = 'CORRSECRETARY') AS CorrespondingSecretaries,
       SUM(O_TYPE = 'RECORDINGSECRETARY') AS RecordingSecretaries,
       SUM(O_TYPE = 'TREASURER') AS Treasurers,
       SUM(O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR' AND ADV_CODE = 'B') AS ChiefAdvisors,
       SUM(O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR' AND ADV_CODE <> 'B') AS OtherAdvisors

FROM chap
INNER JOIN CHS ON chap.chp_id = CHS.chp_id
INNER JOIN chrs ON CHS.CHP_ID = chrs.CHP_ID AND active = 'Y'
WHERE O_TYPE IN ('PRESIDENT', 'VICEPRESIDENT', 'CORRSECRETARY', 
                 'RECORDINGSECRETARY', 'TREASURER', 'ADVISOR')
  AND Term_expire >= DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
  AND Term_Begin <= DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

GROUP BY chap.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation should do what you want.  In SQL Server, I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT chap.name AS Chap,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chs.O_TYPE = 'PRESIDENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Presidents,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chs.O_TYPE = 'VICEPRESIDENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VicePresidents,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chs.OFFICER_TYPE = 'CORRSECRETARY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CorrespondingSecretaries,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chs.O_TYPE = 'RECORDINGSECRETARY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RecordingSecretaries,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chs.O_TYPE = 'TREASURER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Treasurers,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chs.O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR' AND ADV_CODE = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ChiefAdvisors,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chs.O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR' AND ADV_CODE <> 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OtherAdvisors
FROM chap JOIN
     CHS
     ON chap.chp_id = CHS.chp_id JOIN
     chrs
     ON CHS.CHP_ID = chrs.CHP_ID AND 
WHERE chrs.active = 'Y' AND
      chap.O_TYPE IN ('PRESIDENT', 'VICEPRESIDENT', 'CORRSECRETARY', 
                      'RECORDINGSECRETARY', 'TREASURER', 'ADVISOR'
                     ) AND
     chap.Term_expire >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
     chap.Term_Begin <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
GROUP BY chap.name;
```

Note that this also qualifies all column names and simplifies the date arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT chap.Name AS [Chap]
    ,SUM(IIF(chs.O_TYPE = 'PRESIDENT',1,0)) AS [Presidents]
    ,SUM(IIF(chs.O_TYPE = 'VICEPRESIDENT',1,0)) AS [VicePresidents]
    ,SUM(IIF(chs.O_TYPE = 'CORRSECRETARY',1,0)) AS [CorrespondinSecretaries]
    ,SUM(IIF(chs.O_TYPE = 'RECORDINGSECRETARY',1,0)) AS [RecordingSecretaries]
    ,SUM(IIF(chs.O_TYPE = 'TREASURER',1,0)) AS [Treasurers]
    ,SUM(IIF(chs.O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR' AND chs.ADV_CODE = 'B',1,0)) AS [ChiefAdvisorsB]
    ,SUM(IIF(chs.O_TYPE = 'ADVISOR' AND chs.ADV_CODE <> 'B',1,0)) AS [ChiefAdvisorsNotB]
FROM chs
INNER JOIN chrs ON chrs.CHP_ID = chs.CHP_ID AND chrs.Active = 'Y' /*works as filter*/
INNER JOIN chap ON chap.CHP_ID = chs.CHP_ID
WHERE chs.O_TYPE IN ('PRESIDENT', 'VICEPRESIDENT', 'CORRSECRETARY', 'RECORDINGSECRETARY', 'TREASURER', 'ADVISOR')
    AND DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0) BETWEEN chs.Term_Begin AND chs.Term_expire
GROUP BY chap.Name
;
```